# Ascii value of Alphanumeric String

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

Hi is there anyway to get ascii value of Alphanumeric String without reading single character at a time .
For eg if I enter A ,output should be 65.
If I enter Onkar123#. How to calculate ascii of this string?
Also I want sum of ascii value produced by the above string.

Comment: `If I enter Onkar123#` - what would the expected output be and why? Why do you care if a tool reads one char at a time or not? What have you tried so far? See [ask].

Comment: I have made below function   ASCII() {
  num_val=`echo "$1"|od -N 1 -i|head -1|tr -s " "|cut -d " " -f 2`
  echo "$num_val"
}
this is returning ascii value of 1 character at a time. I have to calculate sum of all the ascii value of a word. like here i have to do sum of ascii of onkar123#

Comment: Don't put information that's missing from your question in comments below your question, instead [edit] your question to contain all relevant information. Also, don't just say "I have to do...", actually show the result of whatever it is you have to do **that** is the missing expected output. Also state why a tool that reads the input 1 char at a time is unacceptable as I can't imagine why you'd care about that (or even how you'd test if a given tool does or doesn't do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idk what kind of output you expect, nor do I know why you care if the string is processed one char at a time or how you'd know if a given tool is going one char at a time (and how else COULD any tool be doing this anyway?) so idk if this is the kind of answer you're looking for or not but maybe this will point you in a direction at least:

```
$ printf '%s' "Onkar123#" | awk -l ordchr -v RS='.{1}' '{print ord(RT)}'
79
110
107
97
114
49
50
51
35
```

The above uses GNU awk for `ord()` in the `ordchr` library.

Based on one of your comments, it sounds like this might be what you're looking for:

```
$ printf '%s' "Onkar123#" | awk -l ordchr -v RS='.{1}' '{s+=ord(RT)} END{print s+0}'
692
```

Comment: Actually I have made a function which calculates ascii of one character at a time. but I am also using sum of ascii of character for my algorithm. so I am calling same function twice.

Comment: I updated my answer given one of the other comments you had made under another answer but **please** just edit your question to contain all relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `echo "test" | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x " "\n"'` by replacing `test` with `Onkar123#` or anything else

Answer (score 0):

**od**

There's really no such thing as *the* ASCII value of a string. There *is* such a thing as the decimal (or octal, or hexadecimal) value of each ASCII character *in* a string, though.

Since you don't seem to have hexdump, try the `od` (octal dump) utility. I don't think I've ever seen a *nix system that didn't have `od`.

```
$ echo "Onkar123#" | od -An -t d1 
79  110  107   97  114   49   50   51   35   10
```

I guess endianness might come into play. But `od` has a `--endian` argument for that.

**awk**

It's a lot harder in awk. I think you have to build a lookup table, then lookup the decimal code for each character in the input. That means you still have to process one character at a time.

```
# output-decimal-ascii.awk -- write ASCII decimal codes for input
BEGIN {
    # 127 for ASCII; 256 for extended ASCII
    for(n = 0; n < 127; n++) {
        ascii_table[sprintf("%c",n)] = n
    }
}
{
    split($0, arr, "")
    for (i = 1; i <= length(arr); i++) {
        printf("%d ", ascii_table[arr[i]])
    }
    print "\n"
}
$ echo "Onkar123#" | awk -f code/awk/output-decimal-ascii.awk
79 110 107 97 114 49 50 51 35
```

Comment: splitting using a null string (`split($0, arr, "")`) is undefined behavior per POSIX so what that does depends on the version of awk you're using. It'll work in GNU awk but gawk also has an ord() function so you can just write `awk -l ordchr -v FS="" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%d%s", ord($i), (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}'`.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton its working. is there anyway to get sum of these values ? like if I want sum of 79 110 107 97 114 49 50 51 35 10. I mean the sum of ascii of all the charaters . here output should be  696

Comment: Of course, it's only software so you can do anything with it. edit your question to contain all relevant information. I dont know why you think there should be a `10` at the end of your list of values, nor why you think the sum should be `696` with or without that `10`.

Answer (score 0):

To sum the numbers use:

```
echo "test" | od -An -t d1 | xargs | sed "s/ /+/g" | bc
```